# Flask cache gives me 'AttributeError: 'Cache' object has no attribute 'app''

Tags: flask, caching, flask-caching

I am using application factory pattern in which I have initialized my cache

```
from xyz.caching import cache # this is the cache object
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    cache.init_app(app)
    # other relevant variables.
return app
```

My caching.py

```
from flask_caching import Cache
cache = Cache(config={....})
```

When I import this in any file xyz.caching import cache, this works totally fine. However, in my application I have a entry point script, run.py

run.py

```
from xyz.caching import cache

def run_this():
  cache.get('XXX')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_this()
```

After running python run.py, I get the following error

**'AttributeError: 'Cache' object has no attribute 'app''**

Pls. guide me what is wrong in this, why I am getting this error and what is the way to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I got this message because I forgot to initialize the app

```
cache.init_app(app)
```

I would try to debug if this method call is reached before cache.get('XXX') is called.